# Adding 0 as coefficients in matrixes

Tags: r, for-loop, equation-solving, linear-equation

I have matrix `A` with my coefficients, and matrix `x` with the indices of the variables affected.

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,-1,2),2,2)
x <- rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))
```

Each row (on both matrices at the same time) writes an equation. For my example, this would be (the `??` are there to show that the matrix `b` is not affecting my problem):

```
  x1 - 1*x2  =  ?? 
2*x3 + 2*x4  =  ??
```

That means that `x3` and `x4` have `0` as coefficients in the first equation (`0*x3 + 0*x4`). This also happens on the second equation to the other variables.

**Problem:**

I need to make a function that adds the zeros (`0`) to the rows of my matrix `A`.

So far I did a simple function, but it has too issues:

1. It works, but it is too "wordy", and I'm sure that there is a more elegant way to do it -i.e. less lines of code.
2. The current function only considers the case in which each equation has different variables (as shown on the example above). If my second equation has variables `x2` and `x3`, it will still add a `0`, instead of "skipping" that value.

My function is:

```
prepareCoeffs <- function(A, x) {
  # Create new coefficients matrixes
  newA <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = nrow(x) * ncol(x))

  # Iterate through A
  for(i in 1:nrow(A)) {
    # Prepare row
    newRow <- c()

    # Iterate through x
    for(j in 1:nrow(x)) {
        if(i == j) {
            newRow <- c(newRow, A[i,])
        } else {
            newRow <- c(newRow, rep(0, ncol(x)))
        }
    }

    newA <- rbind(newA, newRow)
  }

  # Return the new matrix
  return(newA)
}
```

The working example can be tested at: http://rextester.com/BHZKL16068

Comment: I'm trying to "fill the gaps (zeros)" on that matrix.

Comment: Are you looking for `M <- matrix(0, nrow(A), max(x));
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) M[i, x[i,]] <- A[i,]` ?

Comment: the numerical values of `x` play no role in the algo, right? just the dimension?!

Comment: whats bad about your already working algo? Is it too slow? Do you wait minutes to get your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do what you need. It uses sparse matrices.

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,-1,2),2,2)
x <- rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))

library(reshape)
x <- melt(x)

library(Matrix)
A <- sparseMatrix(i = x$X1, j = x$value, x = c(A))
#2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#
#[1,] 1 -1 . .
#[2,] .  . 2 2


#example of using the matrix   
A %*% (1:4)
#2 x 1 Matrix of class "dgeMatrix"
#     [,1]
#[1,]   -1
#[2,]   14
```

Comment: This was what I needed! Is there a way to change the `.` to regular `0`?

Comment: Why would you want that? A sparse matrix is memory efficient and convenient. If you must, you can turn it into a dense matrix using `as.matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,-1,2),2,2)
x <- rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4))

M <- matrix(0, nrow(A), max(x))
for (i in 1:nrow(A)) M[i, x[i,]] <- A[i,]
M
# > M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   -1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    2    2
```